# Formatting AJAX request on index page rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I currently have a basic to do list app that displays tasks "to do" and also tasks "completed" on the index page of the app. The model "tasks" has the attribute "completed" which I have a link to in the show page of the task:

```
<%= link_to "Completed", complete_task_path, method: :patch%>
```

The lists update on page refresh, but I'm having trouble actually making an AJAX request to update this information on the index page.

I'm unsure as to what my url should be, as I've tried to use the one provided using "rake routes" in the console.

My complete.js.erb:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log("working");


$('.task_submit_box').click(function() {

  $.ajax({url: '/tasks/:id/complete', success: function(result) {
    $('.task_area').html(result);
    console.log(result);
  }});

});

});
```

My html for displaying the tasks:

```
<ul class="wrapper_task_list">
    <% @task.each do |task| %>


    <% if task.completed == false %>
    <li>
      <div class="task_area", id="incomplete_task_area">
      <%= link_to task.title, task_path(task), class: 'wrapper_task_name'%>
      <%= form_for task, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box :completed, class: 'task_check_box' %>
        <%= f.submit 'update', class: 'task_submit_box' %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

And my complete method in my controller:

```
def complete
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
    @task.update_attribute(:completed, true)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

regarding the route, this is what is displayed for "rake routes" command:

```
complete_task PATCH  /tasks/:id/complete(.:format)  tasks#complete
```

Comment: does your `$.ajax` request get run when you click the button? Check both the Rails and Javascript console for errors and include those here.

Comment: the javascript console reports that the url is not found. I got a 404 response. 

The rails console produces the below:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/complete.js.erb.js

However, my js file is named complete.js.erb, and I do get the "working" log on the console, so I know that it works in some format. 

Additionally, I know that the attribute is updated as when I refresh the page, the task is moved from "incomplete" to "complete", the ajax request just doesn't update the page on the spot.